How can Christianity be considered monotheistic?
How can Christianity be considered monotheistic when they pray to entities other than God, like Jesus, Mary, and saints? The trinity is three, not one. Aren't Christians just finding excuses for idol worship?

Is prayer the same as worship? Does prayer equate to recognition of some entity as a god?

"Christians" is far too broad a category. There are non-Trinitarian denominations for instance. Many others that are Trinitarian do not believe in communicating with saints such as Mary. And even the Catholic Church doesn't teach praying to Mary: "we are not praying to the saints as if they have the power to grant our prayers but rather we are asking them to pray with and for us" (The Cathedral of Saint Patrick: Expressing the Catholic Faith).

I.e. You need to make this question much more specific about what it is asking.

Some identify as 'Christian' who do not even believe in God, and they just think that Jesus of Nazareth was a 'good man'. Some are monotheistic. Some are trinitarian. This site recognises the way things are and studies comparative Christianity as an academic subject. Questions have to be administered in regard to this function. Otherwise, we have a chaotic situation.

Christianity introduced a conception of God that has two axes, not one. In His essence, God is one. In his personhood, God is three.

Unitarian monotheism has one essence, one person
Polytheism has many persons, each with a distinct essence
Christianity has three persons existing with a single shared essence

https://learn.ligonier.org/devotionals/one-essence-three-person

Please don't answer duplicate questions.
